# How to restrict Matcher or Pattern in java?

Tags: java

How to restrict Matcher in java to match only desired String ? Following is the code I have tried, however the expected match should be like "Invoice Received" but it is printing only "Invoice" on console.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class JavaTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<String> actionList = new ArrayList<String>();
        actionList.add("Invoice");
        actionList.add("Invoice Received");

        List<String> notes = new ArrayList<String>();
        notes.add("Invoice Received123");

        for (String note : notes) {
            for (String action : actionList) {

                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(action);
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(note);

                if(matcher.find()) {
                    System.out.println("Update History As : "+action);

                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: If you just want to search for a String why don't you just use String.indexOf() instead of pattern matching

Comment: You search for `Invoice`, you find it and print it out, then you break out of the loop and don't run the `Invoice Received` part at all. And of course this is complete abuse of regular expressions.

Comment: @brso05 It prints only "Invoice" but we just only need "Invoice Received" as output

Answer (score 1):

```
            if(matcher.find()) {
                System.out.println("Update History As : "+action);
                break;
            }
```

This is breaking your code. Literally. The `break` statement exits the inner `for` loop when there is a pattern match. As a result, `Invoice Recieved` never has a chance to be matched.

Originally this was the interpreted issue, but the question has since become about flow control for this particular problem. As a suggested solution, here is an example of the `Note` object *without* polymorphism, but rather a control code.

```
public class Note {
    public static final int INVOICE = 1;
    public static final int INVOICE_RECEIVED = 2;

    public int noteType;
    public String userText;

    public Note(int noteType, String userText) {
        this.noteType = noteType;
        this.userText = userText;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        switch(noteType) {
            case INVOICE:
                // do something with the INVOICE type
                break;
            case INVOICE_RECEIVED:
                // do something with the INVOICE_RECEIVED type
                break;
         }
    }

}
```

Then, you can then create a Invoice Received `Note` object by `Note newNote = new Note(Note.INVOICE_RECEIVED, "this is some user text");` and add them to a list, similar to what you are doing, and handle them accordingly. Depending on the amount of notes you have, a polymorphic design might be better, or at least cleaner. But this is the way of doing it using control codes.

Comment: I have just edited my question & I just want "Invoice Received", could you please check now ?

Comment: You're adding "Invoice" and "Invoice Received" to ```actionsList```, which is an ```ArrayList```. You then loop through the ```ArrayList``` for each ```action```. So, you can either remove the "Invoice" from the ```ArrayList``` or not use a loop and the array list, and just search for the one String. The way your code works is to search for ALL ```action```s in ```actionsList```.

Comment: Correct, there are multiple values in array list, & we need that, but as per the value we receive in "notes" List, we need to find the matching value from "actions" List & hit update with that value. For e.g. "Invoice Received" should be used as an update because we are getting that in notes

Comment: Away from Matcher, any other way or suggestion for implementation will also be okay :), Can you suggest something ?

Comment: To be honest, I'm confused as to what you expect your code to do - you only want it to match "Invoice Received", but you're trying to get it to match both "Invoice" and "Invoice Received" and output what was matched? The way your code works is that it will output ANY match that's in the ```actionsList```, not just the first one - the break stops this, but it still does not guarantee that you'll find the *best* match - rather only the first one that matches at all.

Comment: How do you think we can get it done then, ? but the output that we expect is only should be "Invoice Received" & not "Invoice", considering the value of note i.e. "Invoice Received123" for example. :)

Comment: Your least-effort change to the code would be to either remove "Invoice" from your ```ArrayList```, or revert back to inserting the original ```break``` statement and putting "Invoice Recieved" into ```ArrayList``` *first* as opposed to second. You can also search for a String by the ```.indexOf()``` method, which may be cleaner for your purposes as suggested by @cool

Comment: The only issue here is , we have to compare the value of note with action , it is because note section is manual i.e. combination of action <Coming from checkboxes> + text as per user's choice & so we are doing it this way, any suggestion please ?

Comment: Why not create a ```Note``` object, which has a control code *or* utilizes polymorphism, which contains a ```String``` for user text? Flow control could be more clean if you do it this way.

Comment: There's a simple example of how this could be done. You'd still need to rig it elsewhere, but this would handle the control flow.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to order the patterns that you are looking for so that prefixes of one pattern always come after that pattern. In concrete term:

```
List<String> actionList = new ArrayList<String>();
actionList.add("Invoice Received"); /* Make this take precedence... */
actionList.add("Invoice");          /* ... over this. */
```

Then put the `break` back into your match case, or every "Invoiced Received" note will also be handled as an "Invoice" note too:

```
if(matcher.find()) {
  System.out.println("Update History As : "+action);
  break;
}
```

In general this sort of system will be very susceptible to bugs. If you have any control over the input to this process, modify it so that the note type is explicit, instead of guessed from its content.

Comment: The only issue here is , we have to compare the value of note with action , it is because note section is manual i.e. combination of action <Coming from checkboxes> + text as per user's choice & so we are doing it this way, any suggestion please ?